# Fetching data from mysql db and converting in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am fetching data from MySQL it works fine and  converts data in JSON but problem is that if there is any character with apostrophe then it does not show that data.

Here is my code

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("test.db.6420177.hostedresource.com","test","test");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("bassessment", $con);

$AssessmentID=$_GET['AssessmentID'];
$query = "SELECT * from AssessmentResponsesMaster Ar LEFT JOIN AssessmentStandardQuestion Aq ON Aq.QuestionID=Ar.QuestionID where Ar.AssessmentID='$AssessmentID' AND Ar.SectionName ='12'  ";

$res = mysql_query($query,$con) or die('$query gave error: ' . mysql_error());

if (!function_exists('json_encode'))
{
    function json_encode($a=false)
    {
        if (is_null($a)) return 'null';
        if ($a === false) return 'false';
        if ($a === true) return 'true';
        if (is_scalar($a))
        {
            if (is_float($a))
            {
                // Always use "." for floats.
                return floatval(str_replace(",", ".", strval($a)));
            }

            if (is_string($a))
            {
                static $jsonReplaces = array(array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'), array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"'));
                return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $a) . '"';
            }
            else
                return $a;
        }
        $isList = true;
        for ($i = 0, reset($a); $i < count($a); $i++, next($a))
        {
            if (key($a) !== $i)
            {
                $isList = false;
                break;
            }

        }

        $result = array();
        if ($isList)
        {
            foreach ($a as $v) $result[] = json_encode($v);
            return '[' . join(',', $result) . ']';
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($a as $k => $v) $result[] = json_encode($k).':'.json_encode($v);
            return '{' . join(',', $result) . '}';
        }
    }
}


$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Sample JSON data in which it shows QuestionText null where it has an apostrophe:

```
[{"ResponseID":"5157","AssessmentID":"9","QuestionID":"112","ResponseText":"Yes","Assessment Name":"Summit","AssessmentDate":"28-Jun-2014 11:14 AM","AssessmentQuestion":null,"ResponseComment":" ","DepartmentID":"15","SectionName":"12","QuestionText":"Make eye contact, smile and greet the guest or employee immediately."},
 {"ResponseID":"5158","AssessmentID":"9","QuestionID":"113","ResponseText":"na","AssessmentName":"Summit","AssessmentDate":"28-Jun-2014 11:14 AM","AssessmentQuestion":null,"ResponseComment":" "   ,"DepartmentID":"15","SectionName":"12","QuestionText":null}
]
```

Comment: Why you cant use php inbuilt function json_encode?

Comment: please dont create your own function, php has its own function for it that will handle it for you json_encode($yourArray);

Comment: Ok this is old code I was just testing but how to solve the provided issue

Comment: @lauw that is fine but how to solve data issue which does not display

Comment: @user3682355 check my anser for more options read http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php your problem should be resolved with that

Answer (score 0):

dont create your own function. this is just a small example

```
<?php
$array[0] = "I'm";
$array[1] = 'Conf"used';

echo json_encode($array);
//OR
echo json_encode($array,JSON_HEX_APOS);
?>
```

output = 
["I'm","Conf\"used"] 
second output
["I\u0027m","Conf\"used"]

Comment: did you remove the function you made yourself because it as you can read in the manual (+ it also works in my projects) you can give more arguments..... also im curious what PHP version are you using??

Comment: @user3682355 ahhh the option parameter is added in 5.3 so please do yourself a favor and update to php 5.5 your running behind ALOT. (incase your using something like WAMP do not forget to backup your databases, export those first) after that im pretty sure your problems are over

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode function. Which is php library function.
Please check the manual of this function. [Click Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).